# Obtain CLD from TukeyHSD test

Tags: r, emmeans, tukey

I have been struggling for a while to make my own CLDs from the output of a TukeyHSD test.

First I've done a two-way ANOVA:

```
aov2_arbuscular <- aov(arbuscular_count ~ block + pesticide*fertilizer, data = main_trial)
```

And did a TukeyHSD test as a post hoc test:

```
tk_arbuscular <- TukeyHSD(aov2_arbuscular)
```

Because I could not generate the CLD with the TukeyHSD output I used the emmeans() and cld() function.

```
tk_arbuscular_model <- emmeans(aov2_arbuscular, 
                    pairwise ~ pesticide*fertilizer, 
                    adjust = "tukey")

tk_arbuscular_model_cld <- cld(tk_arbuscular_model$emmeans, 
                    alpha = .05,
                    Letters = letters)
```

I thought that both the TukeyHSD and emmeans with adjust  = "tukey" result in the same output. Which they do for the most results, with unfortunately a few exceptions.
I have already written my result part and do not want to adjust all the p-values again. Therefore, can someone help me to generate the CLDs with the TukeyHSD output, so I can integrate them in a ggplot?

Comment: Why do you suppose `TukeyHSD()` is giving different answers? I'm pretty confident in what emmeans does, so that makes me think your TukeyHSD results are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your data, so I am creating my own reprex that can also be analyzed as a two-factorial block design, i.e. with a model similar to yours.

As you can see, I could not reproduce your problem - all p-values are basically identical. I noticed that you added the `adjust = "Tukey"` to the `emmeans()` statement, but I usually add it to the `cld()` statement instead - however that shouldn't be the problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)

dataURL <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SchmidtPaul/DSFAIR/master/data/Gomez%26Gomez1984.csv"
dat <- read_csv(dataURL) %>% 
  filter(G %in% c("A", "B") & N %in% c("N1", "N2")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rep:N), as.factor)

aov <- aov(yield ~ G + N + G:N + rep, data = dat)


# get contrasts via 3 options ---------------------------------------------
option1 <- stats::TukeyHSD(aov) %>% 
  pluck("G:N") 

option2 <- emmeans::emmeans(aov, ~ G:N) %>% 
  emmeans::pairs(adjust = "Tukey") 

option3 <- emmeans::emmeans(aov, ~ G:N) %>% 
  multcomp::cld(adjust = "Tukey", details = TRUE)


# uniform format ----------------------------------------------------------
option1 <- option1 %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "contrast") %>% 
  transmute(contrast = contrast,
            estimate = diff,
            p.value = `p adj`)

option2 <- option2 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::select(contrast, estimate, p.value)

option3 <- option3 %>% 
  pluck("comparisons") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::select(contrast, estimate, p.value)


# compare -----------------------------------------------------------------
option1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   contrast  estimate p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 B:N1-A:N1     53.3  0.999 
#> 2 A:N2-A:N1   1419.   0.0860
#> 3 B:N2-A:N1   1729.   0.0401
#> 4 A:N2-B:N1   1366    0.0984
#> 5 B:N2-B:N1   1676    0.0455
#> 6 B:N2-A:N2    310    0.910
option2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   contrast    estimate p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A N1 - B N1    -53.3  0.999 
#> 2 A N1 - A N2  -1419.   0.0860
#> 3 A N1 - B N2  -1729.   0.0401
#> 4 B N1 - A N2  -1366    0.0984
#> 5 B N1 - B N2  -1676    0.0455
#> 6 A N2 - B N2   -310.   0.910
option3
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   contrast    estimate p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 B N1 - A N1     53.3  0.999 
#> 2 A N2 - A N1   1419.   0.0860
#> 3 A N2 - B N1   1366    0.0984
#> 4 B N2 - A N1   1729.   0.0401
#> 5 B N2 - B N1   1676    0.0455
#> 6 B N2 - A N2    310.   0.910

tibble(
  o1_p = option1$p.value,
  o2_p = option2$p.value,
  o3_p = option3$p.value
) %>% cor()
#>           o1_p      o2_p      o3_p
#> o1_p 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9967731
#> o2_p 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9967731
#> o3_p 0.9967731 0.9967731 1.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does this help? If not, can you try to create [a reproducible example](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/index.html) with [your data](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html) so that we have all the information?

Also, [here](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/dsfair_quarto/summaryarticles/compactletterdisplay.html) is a chapter I wrote on using and interpreting the compact letter display.